# How to redirect in ruby on rails app from old sites url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

I am updating my site from PHP to Ruby on Rails. How to redirect from old pages?

example:

old page: `/index.php?p=v&tag=__some_word__`

new page: `/tags/__some_word__`

Comment: It's hard to give a solution given just the information you've provided. In your example, the query parameters `tag=someWord` get converted to the path `/tags/someWord`. How would the mapping work if the php route had multiple query parameters? In your example, how would you know to ignore the `p=v` part?

Comment: This should be better done with your http server (apache/nginx/..), not with rails.

Comment: Yes, ?p=v to ignore. I need only &tag parameter. I write into inginx config file:

location / {
                rewrite ^/index.php?p=v&tag=(.*)$ /tags/$1/ permanent;
        }

But redirect don't worked. Perhaps I am wrong to create a rules

Answer (score 1):

At first @mudasobwa is right and it's common to move such rewriting to the proxy server.

But I faced the same situation some years before and I had no access to the nginx config. My solution was to create a another controller to handle old php requests:

```
get "/index.php", :to => 'php_path_handler#index'

# params: {"p"=>"v", "tag"=>"__some_word__", "controller"=>"php_path_handler", "action"=>"index"}
```

In the action I decided how to handle the request based on different parameters and their values. In some cases I just returned a 404 or 410 error. For other cases I redirected to another controller action with status 301 to indicate that there is a new route now.

Another thought: For other maintainers/programmers it could be hard to see how the handling/rewriting of old php routes is done, if you move it to nginx or something else. You could say, you would move some app logic to the proxy server. This is hard to test in development and test environments.